# How to input special characters without locale support?

Tags: linux, locale

I have a linux device and it is not possible to use locale. But I have to support locale keyboard layouts. Thus on press of `input.h #define KEY_LEFTBRACE      26` the character `+` (Plus) shall be displayed. I can map scancodes to KEY_XXX. But how do I map such a key to the character?

Comment: Is that a programming question? If so what language are you using? Do the specs really say that when the user strikes `'{'` s/he should obtain a `'+'`. Normally the keyboard layout is set at the system level (`keymap` or `xmodmap`)...

Comment: Best way would be to do it for the whole system and just with configuration, triggered by udev.
I can use c, c++ and bash. 
`keymap` is not installed on my system. But I'm trying to build it.